# Need to pass a function as a parameter from Android to JNI interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have the following function:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_vidyo_vidyomod_services_VidyoCommands_Login(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis,
                                                                jstring vidyoportalName, jstring userName, jstring passwordName, jobject callback) {

FUNCTION_ENTRY;
const char *portalC = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, vidyoportalName, NULL);
const char *usernameC = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, userName, NULL);
const char *passwordC = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, passwordName, NULL);
jclass loginClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, callback);
VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO_FORMATTED("Login() NDKMETHOD1 Starting Login Process BEFORE %d" , loginClass);
methodClass = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, loginClass,  "onResponse", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO_FORMATTED("Login() NDKMETHOD1 Starting Login Process BEFORE 2%d" , methodClass);

VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("Login() NDKMETHOD Starting Login Process");
VidyoClientInEventLogIn event = {0};

strlcpy(event.portalUri, portalC, sizeof(event.portalUri));
strlcpy(event.userName, usernameC, sizeof(event.userName));
strlcpy(event.userPass, passwordC, sizeof(event.userPass));

VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO_FORMATTED("Login() NDKMETHOD login with portalUri %s user %s ", event.portalUri, event.userName);
VidyoClientSendEvent(VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_LOGIN, &event, sizeof(VidyoClientInEventLogIn));
FUNCTION_EXIT;
```

}

And I get an out event back, that I am trying to handle like this (calling the onResponse method of the interface I'm trying to send to the NDK):

```
 // Send message to Client/application
    VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_IN sign in successful");
    jboolean isAttached;
    VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_OUT sign in successful2");
    JNIEnv *env;
    VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_OUT sign in successful3");
    env = getJniEnv(&isAttached);
    VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD1 VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_IN mid has been initialised");
    jstring js = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
    VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD1 VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_IN js string created");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, methodClass, js , js);
```

I call the login method like this:

```
    CallbackFromNDK back = new CallbackFromNDK() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String code, String response) {
                Log.i("","GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD got out of it");
                Utils.disposeDone = true;
                loginResolved();
            }
        };
        ((VMBaseActivity)getActivity()).app.vidyoCommands.Login(VidyoModApplication.prefManager.getPortal(getActivity()), user, pass, back);
```

This is from my LoginFragment, which has packaged: `package com.vidyo.vidyomod.activities;`
My interface has this package: `package com.vidyo.vidyomod.interfaces;`

But cause I try to call the login while creating the CallbackFromNDK in the login fragment, I get even for `back.getClass().toString()` this: `com.vidyo.vidyomod.activities.LoginFragment$2`

And in my ndk code, it gets to the `(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, methodClass, js , js);` and I get this error:

```
06-06 17:17:10.335: E/art(26772): JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.vidyo.vidyomod.activities.LoginFragment$2.onResponse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) on instance of com.vidyo.vidyomod.VidyoModApplication
06-06 17:17:10.335: E/art(26772):     in call to CallVoidMethod
06-06 17:17:10.336: E/art(26772): "Thread-1652" prio=5 tid=23 Runnable
06-06 17:17:10.336: E/art(26772):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x32dbe0a0 self=0xedc5fa00
```

Why doesn't it let me call that function?

Comment: use it in the same way ... pass CrudStateCallback object ... then on JNI side get `onResponse` method and call it

Comment: That's what I don't understand. how can I pass it, and then use it on the other side? (jni)

Comment: I added a global jclass loginClass; in my jni file. and do this:
`loginClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, callback);`

Comment: let Java_com_vidyo_vidyomod_services_VidyoCommands_Login has another parameter jobject ... on the java side it will be `CrudStateCallback` ... now on the JNI side you have to get method's id  of onResponse method from passed object and call it

Comment: this is now my function:
`Java_com_vidyo_vidyomod_services_VidyoCommands_Login(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jstring vidyoportalName, jstring userName, jstring passwordName, jobject callback) {`
and `jclass loginClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, callback);` but now I try to do a build.sh and I get this error:
 member reference base type 'jclass' (aka 'void *') is not a structure or union
        loginClass.onResponse("");

Comment: `Java_com_vidyo_vidyomod_services_VidyoCommands_Login(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis,
                                                                jstring vidyoportalName, jstring userName, jstring passwordName, jobject callback)  { /*....*/ callOnResponseOfCallback(callback, code, response);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145970/discussion-between-rosu-alin-and-selvin).

Comment: ok because `loginClass` is jclass and it doesn't had such method(`onResponse`) ... you need to call `jmethodID onResponse = GetMethodID(env, loginClass, "onResponse", "(I;Ljava/lang/String)V) ` on this class and then `CallVoidMethod(env,  callback, onResponse , code, response)`

Comment: Almost there. just 1 question,for the signature, what do I use for Int?

Comment: I edited my response. I went with your logic, I don't get build errors anymore, but it crashes when it tries to instantiate, any ideea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. not  "<onResponse>" but "onResponse" 2. `applicationJniObj` should be `callback`

Comment: Made a new edit